# Xcode IOS how to implement Getfeatureinfo of WMS in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I am using WMSOnGooglemaps sdk for base maps . I can see my layers from geoserver overlayed on google maps but I am stuck at getfeatureinfo request(I want information of layer on click of layer).I am geeting the info on click of layer but it is wrong.

```
 //Code to display layer
    - (void)loadView
    {
        GMSTileURLConstructor urls1 = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger z)
        {
            bbox = bboxFromXYZ(x,y,z);
            NSString *urlKN1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://IPADDRESS/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&layers=gidc:plots_category_wise&bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f&width=768&height=1024&srs=EPSG:900913&format=image/png&transparent=true",
                                bbox.left, bbox.bottom,bbox.right,bbox.top];
            return [NSURL URLWithString:urlKN1];
        };
        GMSTileLayer *tileLayer1 = [GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls1];
        tileLayer1.map = mapView;
    }


        - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView1 didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
        {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
            NSLog(@"Latitude= %f lonitude = %f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            point = [mapView1.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
            //ankita.dutta@hardcastlegis.com

            GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithCoordinate:coordinate coordinate:coordinate];
            NSLog(@"Bounds.minx = %f,%f,%f,%f",bounds.southWest.longitude,bounds.northEast.latitude,bounds.northEast.longitude,bounds.southWest.latitude);
            NSLog(@"Pointer: %d, %d",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x] intValue],[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y] intValue] );



            GMSVisibleRegion region;
            region = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
            GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds1 = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:region];
            NSLog(@"Bounds.minx = %.15f,%.15f,%.15f,%.15f",bounds1.southWest.longitude,bounds1.northEast.latitude,bounds1.northEast.longitude,bounds1.southWest.latitude);
            [self getInfo:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x] intValue] :[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y] intValue] :bounds1.southWest.longitude :bounds1.northEast.latitude :bounds1.northEast.longitude :bounds1.southWest.latitude];

        }

        -(void)getInfo : (int) xValue : (int) yValue :(double)bboxLMin :(double)bboxLMax :(double)bboxRMin :(double)bboxTMax
    {
        // [self showLoadingView:YES];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
                       {
                           NSMutableURLRequest * request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://117.239.80.70:8282/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:4326&bbox=%.15f,%.15f,%.15f,%.15f&styles=&&buffer=40&info_format=application/json&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=gidc:plots_category_wise&query_layers=gidc:plots_category_wise&width=%d&height=%d&x=%d&y=%d",bboxLMin,bboxLMax,bboxRMin,bboxTMax, [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:mapView.frame.size.width] intValue],[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:mapView.frame.size.height] intValue],xValue,yValue]]];



                            NSURLSession * session =[NSURLSession sharedSession];

                           [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
                             {
                                 if (data!=NULL)
                                 {
                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                                    {
                                                        //[self showLoadingView:NO];

                                                        NSMutableDictionary *listDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                        NSLog(@"Responce =%@",listDict);
                                                        NSMutableArray *dataArr = [[listDict valueForKey:@"features"]valueForKey:@"properties"];
                                                        [self response:dataArr];
                                                    });
                                 }

                             }]resume];
                       });
    }
```